# No se muestran las imágenes desde fuera del proyecto con Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, rutas

Estoy desarrollando una app con Spring y no logro ver el fallo de porque las imágenes se suben correctamente desde un formulario y se almacenan en un directorio fuera del proyecto en concreto en /opt/uploads pero luego no muestran en el HTML, se conoce que las rutas no estan bien configuradas.

Configuración de los recursos de la clase WebMvcConfigurer:

```
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);

    registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/opt/uploads/");
}
```

Método que se encarga de guardar las imágenes:

```
@PostMapping("/guardar")
public String guardarImagen(@RequestParam(name = "img", required = false)
                                        MultipartFile foto,
                                        Imagen imagen,
                                        RedirectAttributes flash){

    if(!foto.isEmpty()){
        String ruta = "/opt/uploads/";

        try{
            byte[] bytes = foto.getBytes();
            Path rutaAbsoluta = Paths.get(ruta + foto.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(rutaAbsoluta, bytes);
            imagen.setNombre(foto.getOriginalFilename());

        }catch (Exception e){}

        imagenRepository.save(imagen);
        flash.addFlashAttribute("success", "Foto subida!");
    }

    return "redirect:/dashboard";
}
```

Código HTML utilizado para mostrar las imágenes, en el controlador de mostrar esta vista de Spring simplemente le paso un List al modelo para mostrar las imagenes:

```
 <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 text-center mb-3 mt-3"
        th:each="imagen : ${imagenes}"
    >
            <img class='example-image' width="100%" th:src="@{'/uploads/' + ${imagen.nombre}}"
            th:alt="${imagen.nombre}"/>

    </div>
```

[image: Resultado:]

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de donde me estoy equivocando?
Gracias, un saludo.